# Youtube PlayVideoAt() always plays the first video

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm trying to randomly play videos in a Youtube playlist.  I know that there's a bug in the setShuffle function so I am going to randomly generate a random number and then play that video with the .playVideoAt function.

The problem is that when I execute the .playVideoAt function, it ignores it and just plays the first video.  Here's my code to initiate the player (standard stuff):

```
var player;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            height: '390',
            width: '640',
            playerVars: 
      {
        listType:'playlist',
        list: 'PLmHQS8zAl1Bd5elzBYWqucXDK-wv1Xfha'
      },
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });


    }
```

And my code for to start the player.  For testing, I just set it to video 2 (there are a total of 4).

```
 function onPlayerReady(event) {

        player.setLoop(true);
        event.target.playVideoAt(2);

    }
```

Is there something about the playVideoAt function I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

You are directly effected by a bug - playVideoAt() wipes out the playlist.

Steps to reproduce issue:

1. goto: https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo
2. content: 'load a playlist' and add a playlist ID
3. click 'Next' - note that nextVideo(); has no value where it should show value for the next video.

Google forums thread: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/youtube/buTk8H36mEs/ridlaT-c_YIJ